# Get numbers from a file and add

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have been trying to solve problem from a programming site and the data is as below.
 content in my text file as below.

```
2
100
3
5 75 25
200
7
150 24 79 50 88 345 3
```

The first number gives the number of test cases, here it is 2, and the number after it is the sum and the next line is the size of array followed by the array elements (numbers). I need to sum the array numbers and match with the sum that is given and print the position of the numbers that match the sum.

In the above case the results should be:

```
2, 3
1, 4
4, 5
29, 46
11, 56
4, 5
40, 46
16, 35
55, 74
7, 9
```

I managed to get this manually but unable to figure out how to do this from a text file.

The code I used to get the values:

```
public class StoreCredit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Avail=200;
        int[] pri={150, 24, 79, 50, 88, 345, 3};

        for(int i=0;i<pri.length-1;i++){
            for(int j=i+1; j<=pri.length-1;j++){
                int sum=pri[i]+pri[j];
                //System.out.println(pri[i]+", "+pri[j]+" is "+sum);
                if(sum==Avail){
                    System.out.println((i+1)+", "+(j+1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code I used to get the values from text file:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FromFile {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("D:/A1.txt"));
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (s.hasNext()){
            list.add(s.next());
        }
        System.out.print(list);
        s.close();
    }
}
```

When I ran the above code, I got the below output.

```
[2, 100, 3, 5, 75, 25, 200, 7, 150, 24, 79, 50, 88, 345, 3]
```

How can the data be read from file (the sum, the number of inputs with arraysize etc.)?

Comment: You might want to create methods with proper input arguments instead of main methods. Then you could pass the read arrays to your algorithm. The ArrayLists are not required here.

Comment: is your problem with reading the values or the algorithm that solves the presented problem ? if it is about the algorithm please post the link to the problem so we can read it

Comment: Hi C@ME64, I've updated my question with the code and the link to the question is not available, this is a very old question I'm having just the docs with me all the puzzle challenges. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the test case count.

```
int testCaseCount = scanner.nextInt();
```

Loop over the number of test cases.

```
for (int i = 0; i < testCaseCount; i++)
```

Read the sum.

```
   int sum = scanner.nextInt();
```

Read the array size and construct the array.

```
   int arraySize = scanner.nextInt();
   int[] array = new int[arraySize];
```

Loop through the array, populating it.

```
   for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
      array[j] = scanner.nextInt();
```

Do what you want to do with this data.

Comment: Hi Based on your input and array list concept, i've tried the code updated in my answer with the error i get, please have a look into it.

Comment: @user2423959 `while (s.next() != null){ list.add(s.next()); }` should be just `list.add(s.nextInt());` (the `ArrayList` should probably be an `ArrayList` of `Integer` rather than `String`). Otherwise you just keep looping until you run out of elements. The surrounding for-loop takes care of calling `nextInt` the correct amount of times. Also note that it would be easier to just use `nextInt` as opposed to `next` and converting the returned `String` to an integer.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer but still i get the same error. I just want to know, in my text file the values are separated by comma as shown in my question, does this make any difference?

Comment: @user2423959 By my previous comment, I meant you have to **remove** `while (s.next() != null)` and just keep the `list.add`. If the numbers are separated by comma's, you should get an `InputMismatchException` (not `NoSuchElementException`) - if this happens, the easiest solution is to change what Java uses as a separator - this could be changed by calling `s.useDelimiter("[,\\s]+")` - this would change the separator from any amount of whitespace to any combination of whitespace and comma's.

Comment: Hi Dueling, thanks for the solution now everything in the console is working fine, but i want to write the output into a text file, I've updated my code with the code i tried, there is only one line printed into the text file, sorry for updating my question multiple times, just trying to figure out by dividing the question into 3 parts, and this would be last. Thanks again

Comment: @user2423959 It would be best to ask that as a separate question, as it seems to be distinct from your initial question (even though it's for the same program).

Comment: Ok Sure Dukeling, i'll ask and update the link here :-)

Comment: Here is the new question link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933501/full-content-is-not-written-into-a-file ,Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with the [Scanner.nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) method to get full lines:

```
["2", "100", "3", "5 75 25", "200", "7", "150 24 79 50 88 345 3"]
```

After that you have to [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) the numbers to get an array of them.

Also consider using the [Scanner.hasNextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29) method to proof, if there is another line in the stream.

Finally process your logic on these values.

Comment: You don't *have* to do it with `nextLine`. Simply using `next` would work perfectly fine (see my answer).

Comment: True! It's another possibility! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Scanner also has a nextInt which is good for this purpose. This will always jump to the next integer and parse it. I belive Dukelings code will generate a compile error as next() returns a String which you have to parse. This should work:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class read{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = null;
        try{
            s = new Scanner(new File("test"));
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        int testCases = s.nextInt();
        for(int testCase=0; testCase<testCases; testCase++){
            int sum = s.nextInt();
            int numberOfCanidates = s.nextInt();
            List<Integer> canidates = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int number = 0; number<numberOfCanidates ;number++){
                canidates.add(s.nextInt());
            }
            solve(sum, canidates);
        }
    }

    public static void solve(int sum, List<Integer> canidates) {
        System.out.print("Trying to solve problem for sum=" + sum + " and candiates { ");
        for(Integer canidate : canidates){
            System.out.print(canidate);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("}");
    }
}
```